# SSH nginx. Сжатие изображений в папке утилитой imagemagik и вложенных папках с фильтром по части имени вложенной папки

Tags: linux, ssh, imagemagick

Есть сервер на котором 4096 папок  в родительской папке (bitrix/upliad/iblock/...)
В этих папках есть изображения очень большого размера
Нашел решение как их сжать

```
for a in `find . -name "*.jpg" -type f`; do echo $a && convert $a -resize 1920 $a; done
```

Но если я его запущу в родительской папке, скрипт будет ОЧЕНЬ долго обрабатывать (в каждой папке около 100 фото)
Вопрос можно ли добавить маску по части имени папки (например все папки начинающиеся на "a")

Comment: Аа, эээ, а при чём тут nginx?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, можно:

```
find ./a* -name "*.jpg" -type f
```

По скорости:

- Используй утилиту Mogrify https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/basics/#mogrify вместо цикла for
- GraphickMagick, наверное, будет быстрее.
- Можно использовать parallel для загрузки всех ядер процессора. Также можно установить переменную MAGICK_THREAD_LIMIT.
- В ImageMagick есть несколько разных функций для уменьшения размеров: resize, scale, sample (самый быстрый), thumbnial. см. https://imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/#other
- **Никогда** не сжимайте таким образом сканированные или сфотографированные документы.